# Get timezone abbreviation without taking into account DST

Tags: php, date, timezone

Using the following I am converting a GMT time into a local time, and returning the string including the timezone. What I would like it to do, is not return the DST abbreviation for the timezone, e.g. always return PST instead of PDT.

Is there an easier way besides a string replacement?

```
function format_date_time( string $datetime, string $timezone = '' ) {
    $gmt_timezone   = new DateTimeZone( 'GMT' );
    $local_timezone = new DateTimeZone( $timezone === '' ? wp_timezone_string() : $timezone );

    $gmt_datetime = new DateTime( trim( $datetime, 'Z' ), $gmt_timezone );
    $offset       = $local_timezone->getOffset( $gmt_datetime );
    $gmt_datetime->add( DateInterval::createFromDateString( (string) $offset . 'seconds' ) );

    $local_datetime = new DateTime( $gmt_datetime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ), $local_timezone );

    return $local_datetime->format( 'l, F jS, Y \a\t g:ia T' );
}
```

Comment: So, do you want the actual local time with the wrong timezone, or do you want adjust the time so you get the time as if daylight saving had not been applied? Either way, I can see this causing more problems than it solves.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Really just want timezones that have DST to reflect the abbreviation as the standard abbreviation, not DST abbreviation. e.g. PST instead of PDT, EST instead of EDT, etc.